# SignalR as a Game Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a board game application that I would like to add multiplayer options, I'm considering using SignalR to do a persistant connection. I'm wondering whether anyone has done something like this, or whether there is an opensource project available that I can have a look at ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking us to recommend or find a library or off-site resource. Also, [GameDev@StackExchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a game written in SignalR - [SignalR ShootR](http://shootr.signalr.net/)

You can take a look at the source code here - [SignalR ShootR Source Code](https://github.com/ntaylormullen/shootr)