# better way to create game server with web interface

Tags: c#, signalr, winforms-to-web

i decided to write a card game with c# that has a winform application for main server to manage the game with a web interface. i chose SignalR self-host for main server. because i want to sell this app to others and dont want to modify the code or html of the web interface. so my question is: is that good for handling 10000 client request? is there a way to write this app for better performance?
another thing is i want to write the main server and login cashout profile and ... most written by customers like poker mavens and i just create a api with json to do this functions. plzzzz guide me which way is better to write this app!

Comment: You question is unclear. Could you elaborate a bit more on what is your exact scenario? Is your game connected to a central server with clients connecting to the server to play the game? Why are you using Winform application as a "Server"? Is this a web browser based game? mobile game? PC game? Also what do you mean by 10000 client request? Does it mean that 10k clients will be online and making concurrent requests? What is a cashout profile?

Comment: @KRoy
first of all tnx for your attention and answer!
i answer your question one by one in below.
my exact secario is [poker mavens](http://www.briggsoft.com/pmavens.htm)
no, my server game is stand alone and player connect to my server with browser.
i'm using winform because i want to sale my game server and dont want to modfiy my code by customers.
browser game base.
mean 10k client connect to my game server and play there game.
yes.
see the link up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your server code self hosted and a javascript client calling into your server methods, becoming your browser based client, your design should work.
I am looking at this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

But I think you'll need to figure out scale out scenarios and server failure scenarios with the self host. In case there is a patch update on the server and it has to restart, you'll need to be able to get a backup. Also consider the case when you need to upgrade the server. So you'll need to be able to host it in multiple servers and you'll need to provide the signalr backplane option.

From a performance point of view, I have tested a web api signalR application on a single 4-core-14-GB server and was able to scale up to 20k connections, with the server comfortably serving more than 200 Requests per second.

With a backplane these numbers were around 100-150 rps. 
The response times in both cases were very good ~ 500 ms.

Although please note that your numbers could be VASTLY different based on your actual functionality.

Comment: verrryy thanks @KRoy for your answer!
i dont know why people give me a downvote? this site for a ask and answer question!! :|
so you suggest me to use signalr? is there a better technique to write this app in windows form?

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you do not have enough details while asking the question. Also generally the questions need to be specific, like implementation of a specific scenario or help on something that is not working, and not broad like designing the system etc. That would be your decision based on your knowledge of technologies and your exact requirements.

Comment: Take a look at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110589/signalr-for-multiplayer-game-development   and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551954/signalr-as-a-game-server?rq=1 .

Comment: To answer you if you can go with SignalR, you could, but that would depend on the kind of load you or your customers expect. For e.g. SignalR is not a good fit for Chat scenarios with huge numbers of users, but its a good fit for broadcast or notification scenarios. Depending on how you design your game, you can use signalR. Try out a test application with minimal features and test out some failure scenarios and load scenarios. If it all holds well, you're good to go.

Comment: By Chat scenario I mean one-on-one chats. For Chat Rooms, which are a broadcast scenario signalr would be a good fit.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261987/is-it-correct-to-use-signalr-for-desktop-applications?rq=1

Comment: +1 very thanks @KRoy for your attention and good answer!!! i read the all of your link and i think the SignalR is my choice!